# How would Eilistraee react to being worshipped by characters outside her target demographics?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, religions-and-deities

I know that for example some gnomes worship Gond (human god) as well as certain elves follow Mystra (also human god), but how would deity like Eilistraee (whose entire existence revolves around drow) react to being worshipped by half-orc or even human? Would she even care or would she just ignored them?

Comment: Are you asking specifically and exclusively about Eilistraee? If not, the question is probably too broad so you should ask about her specifically. Also, is it alright if people use Lore from previous edition of D&D or are you interested solely in lore from fifth edition?

Comment: @Medix2 I'm asking specifically for Eilistraee in fifth edition, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Note, for me, this question is *not* primarily opinion based.  It is asking for Lore and in-universe examples on a very specific event

Comment: @Medix2 Agreed. This question is well scoped - it can be answered directly by citing appropriate lore sources. While there may not be any relevant information in published D&D 5e sourcebooks (there may be, I haven’t checked), it is also conceivable that relevant information may be found in one of the many canonical novels.

Comment: I can't find anything based in 5E lore...but I did fine something in 2E lore. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is very, very little information about Eilistraee in 5th Edition so, regrettably, I can't offer you an answer from the edition you requested.

However, it has generally been my experience that older lore can be considered to hold true unless something in more recent lore contradicts it. So, the only place I can find an answer for you is in the 2nd edition AD&D book "Demihuman Deities."

> Eilistraee also has worshipers of human, elves, and in particular half elven stock

-Page 13, Demihuman Deities

> She often aids creatures she favors (whether they worship her or not) in small practical ways

-p13

> All [clerics] of Eilistraee must be female, but they may be of any intelligent race

-p14

Based on this, it's pretty clear that she accepts worshippers of any race as any female of any intelligent race can become a cleric of hers.

As an addendum by Word of Ed Greenwood (the 'owner' of the Realms whose word is considered canon so long as it's not contradicted)

> yes, there can at the present time in the Realms be male clergy of Eilistraee (no changedance necessary).

Sourced from a compilation of answers found [here](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=19841&whichpage=21#476469)

Comment: Eilistraee has clerics of all genders in the current times, and even offers physical transition to people who want to go from female to male, or male to female. This is straight from Ed Greenwood, whose word is canon unless contradicted by WotC's stuff, and this hasn't been contradicted.

Comment: @Irennan Thanks, I went and sourced that and added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eilistraee is known to accept everyone, of any race, and to have a soft spot for outcasts.

Source: the end of these two sections of the wiki article about her

https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Eilistraee#Personality
https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Eilistraee#Activities

In turn, they cite Demihuman Deities as the source.

Comment: Thank you, do you maybe have a source where was it written?

Comment: This article. It cites its sources as well. https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Eilistraee

"Though focused on the drow, Eilistraee accepted folk of all races who danced along her path, who delighted in life and in the free-form expression of it in all its forms. She fought so that all races could live peacefully together, helping and accepting each other despite their differences," (Demihuman Deities)

Comment: Also,

"Despite her focus on the drow, Eilistraee took to heart the cause of aiding the needy wherever and whenever possible, no matter their race, gender, or strength. She believed in offering kindness, shelter, and acceptance to anyone not working evil, especially if outcasts.[4] She and her church also worked to spread joy and merriment, and to bring confort and hope to those who were taken by sorrow.[4]"

Still Demihuman Deities.

Comment: As a general rule, the stack prefers primary sources, not wikis. I have personally encountered cases where the Forgotten Realms wiki says something and even cites a source for it...but on checking the cited source, the information either doesn't match or isn't there at all.

Comment: Demihuman Deities does agree with all that. In fact, the Wiki quotes pretty much say what that book also says. Then again, the Eilistraee article is a featured one, which means it has been double checked to include correct info. Other articles might not be as reliable.

Comment: @Irennan Demihuman Deities is a 2nd edition source and not a 5e source.  The wiki is at times not up to date or has errors. As such, you need to point to a 5e source. Sorry, still [citation needed]

Comment: @Trish The standard stance about about canon is that older lore continues being canon unless directly contradicted by newer lore. No 5e lore contradicts Demihuman deities, so Demihuman Deities is still canon. The Eilistraee article in the wiki is *very* up to date, till the very latest developments. 

If we were to go by pure 5e lore, the answer to an ungodly amount of questions would be "there's no answer to that, do whatever the hell you want". Demihuman Deities definitely still is a valid source to cite.